# W3C Validation Error: Percentile Height and Width Attributes

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website locally, where I am currently trying to dynamically call a Custom Header.  I am using the following code:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="20%<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="20%<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="header-image" />
```

The above code, outputs the following line to the Browser:

```
<img src="http://localhost/wordpress-folder/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/image.jpg" height="20%3484" width="20%2439" alt="header-image" />
```

Though the above code successfully calls the Custom Header, it does fail W3C Validation.  The error message is as follows:

> Bad value 20%3484 for attribute height on element img: Expected a
>   digit but saw % instead.

The only way I can seem to remove this error, is by removing the % (px also produces the error) and only leave in the number.

Is there a way I could continue using Pixels/Percentage other than reorganising my code, so that I could implement some Inline/External Style Sheets?

Comment: Height and Width attributes are assumed to be in pixels. Either remove anything but numbers or use the style attribute.  `style="width:100px;height100;"`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: @bassxzero Thank you.  I tried this initially and whilst it worked, it enlarged the image to cover the entire screen; even when the px was set to 1.  I noticed that if I removed `<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>` as well, the problem was solved.  Thank you.  Also, thank you for sharing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using HTML height and width attributes. When you pass values to them you cannot pass the metric (e.g.: %, px etc) to it.

You will have to change your line to:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="header-image" />
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you.  I totally overlooked the fact that `<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>` was dynamically calling the relevant attributes.  Thus explaining the error since I was manually inputting the attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

This should throw an error as it's not in a correct format. It should be either in % format or px format. `20%3484` is an incorrect format.

If you want to give fixed height, you can use this:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="header-image" />
```

or if you want to use `%`, then use this:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="20%" width="20%" alt="header-image" />
```

But you can only use one of them.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Your second suggestion stills throws an error with validation, due to the %.  Your first suggestion works, though we do not need to place the additional 'px' :-) Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem. I think we just have to remove px.